# Selecting N first rows with the biggest value of an attribute using JOIN with the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say that I have simple database like this:

```
People
name    age
Max     25
Mike    15
Lea     22
Jenny   75
Juliet  12
Kenny   10
Mark    44
```

and I want to select N the oldest people from there by using JOIN with People table itself. I've tried to JOIN them this way

```
People p1 JOIN People p2 ON p1.age < p2.age
```

to be able to COUNT number of people in p2 that are elder from specific one in p1 and then filter the result according to this number, but I don't know how to COUNT it and if the way I JOIN these tables is correct :)

For N = 4 expected result is:

```
name     age
Jenny     75
Mark      44
Max       25
Lea       22
```

Comment: Add the expected result! (For some N values.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you meant to do is:

```
SELECT t.name,t.age FROM (
    SELECT p1.name,p1.age,count(*) as cnt FROM People p1
    JOIN People p2ORDER ONBY p1.age < p2.age
    GROUP BY p1.name,p1.age) t
WHERE t.cnt <= N
```

But there is not need for that, you can use ORACLE's `rownum`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM People p1
    ORDER BY p1.age DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= N
```

Comment: Are you sure t.count in last lane is correct? I can't figure what does it mean :)

Comment: @RIPI Meant to be cnt :) Corrected

Comment: The first one is exactly what I meant. But...I've just created exactly the same table as I invented in this example and there is one problem :) How to present the age next to the names? age or t.age doesnt work :)

Comment: @RIPI I updated the answer, the second solution will bring both columns, and now the first one will too

Comment: Ok, now it's nice and exactly what I meant. It has some problem as it returns Mark as the oldest one and completely ignores Jenny in results, but I will figure out why is that so :)

Answer (score 1):

Newer Oracle versions support `FETCH FIRST`:

```
select *
from people
order by age desc
fetch first 4 rows only
```

You can also try: `fetch first 4 rows with ties`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join, simple ordering a nested query:

```
select *
from (
        select *
        from people
        order by age desc
     )
where rownum <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a join, just do

```
select * from
(select p1.name,p1.age, row_number() over (order by p1.age desc) order_n from people)
where order_n <=N
```

(If I interpreted your question correctly)